# AS3 Get the current class name from a static method

Tags: actionscript-3, class, reflection, static

i have to read the current class name inside a static method. For non-static method it's easy i just call getQualifiedClassName(this) but inside a static method this is off course invalid. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use getQualifiedClassName(prototype.constructor) 
in the class' static method

Comment: You have to give class name before `prototype`, like `MyClass.prototype.constructor`...you cant directly call `prototype.constructor` inside static function of `MyClass`. Is there a way not to specify `MyClass`? I'm looking for a solution as well...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a direct way of doing this. If is just inside one class that you need this, you can try to add a static member holding a reference to the class.

```
static private const CLASS:Object = YourReflectedClass;
```

then, just use that in your static method:

```
protected static function doReflection(): void {
   var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(CLASS);
}
```

It would be helpful to know more about the use and the setup.

Comment: You are right maybe you need some more info. I'm writing a class with the static method. This class is an abstract class extended from many classes inside our project. The problem is that class names are important to my method and during compile time i don't know the name of the subclass used. Now my code works using a non static method but it's inelegant because we have to instantiate a new object just to call a method that can be static

Comment: I'm not sure im following all the way, the only thing you need is the name of the class of each instance and want to gather that info in a method that is in the abstract class?

Comment: yes i have a class ParentClass with ParentClass.staticMethod() and from a ChildClass -> ChildClass extends ParentClass i can call the method ChildClass.staticMethod(). Inside this method i have to read the string "ChildClass" the name of the subclass that called the method.

Comment: right, but from where are you thinking to access staticMethod()? You can't override static methods